# List EVERYTHING in Desktop folder

Tags: c#, windows, desktop, c#-2.0

So here's the thing...
I'm making a small app that should be able to list EVERYTHING on a users Desktop - including shortcuts.

So I was doing this:

```cs
string filepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);

            foreach (var file in d.GetFiles())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
            }
```

That gives me the following:

```
 Spotify.lnk  
 Desktop.ini
```

But on my Desktop I can see these:

```
Spotify.lnk
Desktop.ini
Microsoft Office 2010
VLC Media Player
```

So I tried to pull some WMI info from: Win32_ShortcutFile without any luck.
(It lists stuff I don't have on the desktop like Windows Live.)

So at the moment I'm kind of clueless...

I hope this made any sense!

Any pointers in the right direction would be awesome!

Cheers.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mentioned - the target node is a Windows Server 2008 SP1 machine.

**EDIT:** I also forgot to mention that I am already checking for folders on the desktop.

Comment: You need a check for folders too.

Comment: Yeah, sorry forgot to mention that - I have that check implemented as well.

Comment: You also need to check the Public user's (or All Users in XP) Desktop for items.

Comment: I think in XP you need to add the All Users/Desktop folder manually.

Comment: @Johnny - Forgot to mention that too - the target nodes will run Windows Server 2008 SP1. I'll add it to my question! Thanks

Comment: Not everything on a user's Desktop is represented as a file or directory on the filesystem. Do you want "virtual" files, like the Recycle Bin, too?

Comment: @Gabe - Nope Recycle Bin should be ignored. It's the only file that is allowed on the servers desktop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to check the public user's desktop.

In .Net 4.0 and above, you can use the `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory` special folder to get at that directory.

On your machine it is probably `C:\Users\Public\Desktop` if you have not changed it.  If you look in there, you should see the files that are missing from the `C:\Users\YourUserName\Desktop` folder.

If you are on .net 3.5 or below, then the `CommonDesktopDirectory` does not exist in the special folder enum.  If that is the case, you will need to use a Win32 API call to get the folder path.

```
[DllImport("shfolder.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern int SHGetFolderPath(IntPtr hwndOwner, int nFolder, IntPtr hToken, int dwFlags, StringBuilder lpszPath);
private const int MAX_PATH = 260;
private const int CSIDL_COMMON_DESKTOPDIRECTORY = 0x0019;
public static string GetAllUsersDesktopFolderPath()
{
    StringBuilder sbPath = new StringBuilder(MAX_PATH);
    SHGetFolderPath(IntPtr.Zero, CSIDL_COMMON_DESKTOPDIRECTORY, IntPtr.Zero, 0, sbPath);
    return sbPath.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Also you need to scan this directory:

```
string filepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get All destop items you will have to check `DesktopDirectory` and `CommonDesktopDirectory`

```
    var list = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)).GetFiles()
       .Concat(new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory)).GetFiles())
       .Distinct();

    foreach (var file in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

While many of the items come from the All Users Desktop, as explained in other answers, that by no means completes your search.

If you want to use the same list that Windows does for desktop items, you need to call `SHGetDesktopFolder` and invoke `EnumObjects` on the resulting object.  I don't think the .NET Base Class library exposes this functionality, but I'm sure someone has already written a wrapper that does all the p/invoke heavy lifting.  There's a thin wrapper (interface declarations converted to C#) already provided at pinvoke.net

Answer (score 0):

Some files may be showing up when you look (but not to code) because they're actually in the shared desktop folder.  On Windows 7, this is `C:\Users\Public\Public Desktop`.  On XP I *think* it's `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop`, but I can't check that right now.

Comment: Hard coding a path like that is not a good approach, because it does not work if users move that folder.  Using the SpecialFolders enum is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @JohnKoerner - Very good point.  It's still good to know what the defaults are so you can manually check that that's the issue.